# How to run jar file on linux hosting?

Tags: linux

I want to run android app server on my hosting so as to get a static IP address. but the problem is .jar file is not being executed on the server. whenever i click on the link of the jar file it starts to download. how can i run that .jar file on my hosting?

Answer (score 0):

from command line execute this:

```
java -jar file.jar
```

But if you want to run android app it is much more complicated

The command to install java on your distribution (as I understand is CentOS) is

```
yum install jre
```

Comment: I am getting the error -bash: java -jar file.jar: command not found.

Comment: So you do not have java installed. Use commands for package management to install it

Comment: that's what i want to know. what will be the procedure to do so.?
can you please post according links here.? thanks in advance.

Comment: You do not specify your linux distribution. On debian based will be something like: `apt-get install java`  on rpm based will be: `yum install java`

Comment: They uses CentOS on their hosting. What will be the command.?

Comment: Check my edited answer please